# Python Dynamic Class Object Names

Tags: python

Just a quick question. I've tried Googling this but every time you add "class" to a Python search it gives you classes on Python. D:

I've found threads like this: [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-to-a-while-loop)

But I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for since concatenation is also part of the variable.

Here's my while loop:

```
def main():
    counter = 1
    while counter <= 3:
        print "Name: ",employee[counter].name
        print "ID Number: ",employee[counter].id_number
        print "Department: ",employee[counter].department
        print "Job Title: ",employee[counter].job_title
        print #LB
        counter = counter + 1

main()
```

I have my objects set up as:

```
employee1 = Employee("Susan Meyers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President")
employee2 = Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer")
employee3 = Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer")
```

This is the error I receive:

```
print "Name: ",employee[counter].name
NameError: global name 'employee' is not defined
```

Obviously I have a class set up as well, but I don't think I need to paste that for this. What I want it to do is go through the loop and change the counter from 1 to 2 to 3. That way it'll loop through all three employees.

Is it possible to do that? I've only ever done this with arrays so I'm not 100% sure I'm on the right track.

Any tips would be great. <3

Chelsea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a list

```
employees = []
for i in xrange(1,10):
    employees.append(employee("some name %s" % i))

employees[4].name
```